# CSS : what is the difference between float: left or align: left?

Tags: css

What is the difference between `float: left` and `align: left` if I want to keep HTML `<div>` elements in left position?

```
#left {
  align: left;
  background: pink;
}
```

vs

```
#left {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: You should check these MDN articles: [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See MDN which has a convenient [list of all CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference#Keyword_index).

[`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) pushes the element it is applied to to the side and allows content that follows it to bubble up beside.

[image: float image]

`align` is not a CSS property and will be ignored.

[image: align is invalid CSS]

---

The type of document level layout it sounds like you want to do is usually best achieved with [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) or [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids).